# How to register platform specific implementations in a Prism module?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to create a Prism module in a Xamarin Forms application. My module contains platform specific code and a view model that takes in an interface for that. For example:

```
ThingModule (PCL)
 ThingModule
   + Initialize()
 IThing
 ThingView
 ThingViewModel(IThing thing)

ThingModule.Droid (Android)
 AndroidThingImplementation : IThing

ThingModule.iOS (iOS)
 iOSThingImplementation : IThing
```

I can register the views for navigation easily enough in the module's Initialize method, but how can I register the platform specific implementations in the module (rather than in the app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't register platform specifics in the module.  You register platform specific in the actual platform specific projects.  Your module just has to have reference to the interface, and that's it.  You can use the IPlatformInitializer to do this.  See a sample here:

Android:
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Sandbox/Xamarin/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.Droid/MainActivity.cs#L28

```
[Activity(Label = "HelloWorld", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
    }
}

public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {

    }
}
```

XF Project:
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Sandbox/Xamarin/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/App.cs#L15

```
public class App : PrismApplication
{
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }
    ...
}
```

Comment: My goal is to have the modules that we create live in a library. We are building multiple applications that would consume this library.

I was hoping for a way for the consumers of the module to not have to remember (or even know) that they have to register the platform specific implementations. 

Easy enough to just have the app register them. Thanks!